# Reading text files in a zip archive

Tags: java, zip

I have zip archive that contains a bunch of plain text files in it.  I want to parse each text files data.  Here's what I've written so far:

```
try {
    final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
    final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    ZipInputStream zipInput = null;

    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
        if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
            final String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
            if (fileName.endsWith(".txt")) {
                zipInput = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
                final RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
                String line;
                while((line = rf.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                rf.close();
                zipInput.closeEntry();
            }
        }
    }
    zipFile.close();
}
catch (final IOException ioe) {
    System.err.println("Unhandled exception:");
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Do I need a RandomAccessFile to do this?  I'm lost at the point where I have the ZipInputStream.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, you don't need a `RandomAccessFile`. First get an `InputStream` with the data for this zip file entry:

```
InputStream input = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
```

Then wrap it in an `InputStreamReader` (to decode from binary to text) and a `BufferedReader` (to read a line at a time):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

Then read lines from it as normal. Wrap all the appropriate bits in `try/finally` blocks as usual, too, to close all resources.

Comment: Hi Jon, I am looking for the similar solution, only difference is I would be reading text from different formats and using Tika to read these files. any pointers?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file

Comment: @SJagdeesh: I don't know what Tika even is. I'll look at your question, but I don't know whether I'll be able to help.

Comment: What if there are multiple files and I also want their filenames?

Comment: @bonapart3: Then you would use `entry.getName()`, as the code in the question already does.