# Get files from a zip file

Tags: java, jar, zip

In java, a jar/zip file is identicall to an directory.

I'll like to get a file from a jar/zip file as if were
a directory.

Any one know where to look for.

Comment: "In java, a jar/zip file is identicall to an directory." ... you've been lied to.

Comment: A jar can be added to the class path and a directory can be added to the class path. In that sense, they are equal

Comment: @AndersLindén I can hold an apple in my hand and I can hold in an orange in my hand, therefore in that sense ... they are equal.

Comment: With my answer, I proved that there is a way of treating the file system and jar files in the same way. A more close relation than fruit can have to your hand.

Comment: A jar != directory. Two very different things.

Comment: Yes, they are different and the probability that the OP can see the difference to a relevant degree is high. The formulation is also contradictory because both "identical" and "as if" are used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Content from Files which are inside Zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file)

Comment: But you cannot "get" a file from a jar or zip file as if it were a directory.

Comment: If you use the same interface, you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you seek for?

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
  .getResourceAsStream("SomeTextFile.txt");
```

[How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Comment: It's funny to read that your answer starts with a question while the OP's question actually doesn't state a question :)

Comment: "Any one know where to look for" is a question, although malformatted

Comment: You are right. I took that sentence as invitation to look for an answer ;)