# How to list all the children directories name present inside a specific directory which is present inside zip file in java

Tags: java, zip, inputstream, zipinputstream

Let suppose, I have a zip file 'zipTest', it contains two directories say 'Final' and 'Test' (zip file may contain more directoris as well, for simplicity I mentioned only two). I want to list all the direct children directories name present inside 'Final' directory in java, (I do not want to extract zip file due to some obvious reasons).

[See zip structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juHBE.jpg)

I want to list all the direct children directories for 'Final' directory present inside zip file. Directories name 'a' and 'b' should be listed as they are the direct children of 'Final' directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548755/read-zip-file-content-without-extracting-in-java  This can help

Comment: Create a [Zip file system provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) and use the standard file system functions.