# Java - set path to file in zip

Tags: java

I have something like this:

`File.txt/directory/directory/Main.java`

and all of it is packed in a zip.

What is the correct path to File.txt in Main.java?

Comment: is this in your computer a valid path:??  File.txt/directory/directory/Main.java???

Comment: I mean, I have pack.zip and in this zip I have File.txt/src/task3/Main.java

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot do this: there is (currently) no approach that allows you to point to a file inside a zip file. What you *can* do is read the zip file as a stream and then take the file that you need. For that, I would refer you to [Read Content from Files which are inside Zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file).