# Java 8 FileSystem access file in zip package zipped in another zip

Tags: java, filesystems, zip, java.nio.file

I want to ask if is possible to access and modify a text file inside a zip file which is zipped in another zip package.

I know that can I access the file using Java.nio FileSysten like this. In this example to read all the lines in "sample.txt" file.

```
   FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(new URI("jar:file", "sample/path/to/zipfile/main.zip", null), new HashMap<>());
   readAllLines("sample.txt");
```

where

```
   public List<String> readAllLines(String fileName) {
    List<String> file = new ArrayList<>();
    Path rootDir = fileSystem.getRootDirectories().iterator().next();

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> files = Files.newDirectoryStream(rootDir,
            entry -> entry.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("/" + fileName))) {
        Path path = files.iterator().next();
        file = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
}
```

I want to ask, if is possible to read this "sample.txt" file also if it will be located in 2 zips packages in depth. Like mainzip.zip/sample.zip/sample.txt

```
     mainzip.zip
     |
     |-sample.zip
       |
       |-sample.txt
     |-another.zip
```

of course I do now want to unzip the mainzip.zip.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file) might be a helpful place to start.