# JUnit test zipping of folder

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have implemented a method to zip files. This method is capable of zipping subfolder, overwriting existing zip files and some more. Now I want to create unit tests for this method. I started with a default zip-file with some content so I could test the overwriting etc.

My method to set up the source files:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    util = new ZipFileUtil();

    parent = folder.newFolder("Parent");
    File subfolder = folder.newFolder("Parent", "Subfolder");
    File sub2 = folder.newFolder("Parent", "Subfolder", "Sub2");

    File f1 = File.createTempFile("file1", ".txt", parent);
    File f2 = File.createTempFile("file2", ".txt", parent);
    File f3 = File.createTempFile("file3", ".txt", parent);

    File f4 = File.createTempFile("file4", ".txt", subfolder);
    File f5 = File.createTempFile("file5", ".txt", subfolder);

    File f6 = File.createTempFile("file6", ".txt", sub2);
    File f7 = File.createTempFile("file7", ".txt", sub2);

    File f8 = File.createTempFile("test", ".txt", sub2);

    File f9 = File.createTempFile("test1", ".txt", parent);

    files[0] = f1;
    files[1] = f2;
    files[2] = f3;
    files[3] = f4;
    files[4] = f5;
    files[5] = f6;
    files[6] = f7;
    files[7] = f8;
    files[8] = f9;

    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.zip").toURI());

    Files.copy(file.toPath(), Paths.get(folder.getRoot().toString(), "test.zip"),
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

And my test:

```
@Test
public void testOverwriteFilesInExistingZip() throws IOException {
    util.setZipNameGenerator(new ZipNamingStrategy() {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "test";
        }

    });
    util.setOverwriteFilesInExistingZip(true);
    util.setSourceFolder(parent);
    util.setDestinationFolder(folder.getRoot());
    util.generateZip(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return true;

        }
    });
    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get(folder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath(), "test.zip"), null);

    assertEquals("/" + files[0].getName(),
            fs.getPath("/", parent.toPath().relativize(files[0].toPath()).toString()).toString());
    assertEquals("/" + files[1].getName(),
            fs.getPath("/", parent.toPath().relativize(files[1].toPath()).toString()).toString());
    assertEquals("/" + files[2].getName(),
            fs.getPath("/", parent.toPath().relativize(files[2].toPath()).toString()).toString());
    assertEquals(true,
            new File(fs.getPath("/", parent.toPath().relativize(files[8].toPath()).toString()).toString()).exists());

    assertEquals("/file.txt", fs.getPath("/", "file.txt").toString());
    assertEquals("/New Text Document.txt", fs.getPath("/", "New Text Document.txt").toString());
    assertEquals("/test.txt", fs.getPath("/", "test.txt").toString());
    assertEquals("/test1.txt", fs.getPath("/", "test1.txt").toString());

    assertEquals("/Subfolder/file.txt", fs.getPath("/", "test1.txt").toString());
    assertEquals("/Subfolder/desktop.ini", fs.getPath("/", "test1.txt").toString());
    assertEquals("/Subfolder/test.txt", fs.getPath("/", "test1.txt").toString());
    assertEquals("/Subfolder/New Text Document.txt", fs.getPath("/", "test1.txt").toString());

    assertEquals(15, util.getProcessedFiles());

}
```

I am kinda lost on how to properly check if the zip file has the right structure (files have to exist in the file). Currently I am just checking the paths, but this is so wrong and I know it. Can anyone enlighten me on how to properly test this kind of method?

Comment: This is a little unclear.  Can you just unzip it and check the contents?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth surely i could, but this would mess up the paths probably and i want to check if its all right **inside** the zip file

Comment: Is it correct that `ZipFileUtil` is not a Class that you have written?

Comment: @HerrDerb it's my own class and from what i tested by hand its working as it should

Comment: What do you mean by "mess up the paths"?  Why can't you just unzip into a temporary directory, and compute relative filenames at that point?  That said, it is possible to get Java to directly read content from a zip file (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file), it's just a bit of a pain.  (If that link answers your question, then great!  If not, could you clarify what exactly the remaining issue is?)

Comment: In my opinion you are using way too much files for your test, which makes it very hard to read. As I see two directories where one contains 1 file and the other 2 files would be sufficient, to test the functionality.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth i mean that the paths change then meaning they are no longer in the zip file. also i don't need to check the content, i need to check if the files were being processed at all to make sure it didn't miss any file

Comment: @HerrDerb so like this: parent (1 file), subfolder (1 file) and sub2 (1 file)?

Comment: Ok.  But your code seems to be doing that already, other than the actual existence check (which you can do with `Files.exists(path)`).

Comment: If you have a directory with 2 files, you don't need to test another directory with 3 files. You don't test anything more with this, it only produces more lines within your test, which should be avoided. If you do rootPath/file1, rootpath/sub/file2, /rootpath/sub/file3 you've already got everything covered, don't you? (multiple files and subfolder)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `assertEquals("/" + files[2].getName(),
            fs.getPath("/", parent.toPath().relativize(files[2].toPath()).toString()).toString());` will be true as long as the relative paths match (in my opinion not enough). you are right that i can just test it with `Files.exists(path)`, thanks for this.

@HerrDerb I think so

Comment: This means the half of your `assert` checks actually do not provide anything to quality of the test. I recommend to shorten it down to the necessary then. This way you can take better care for the real testing goal.

Comment: @HerrDerb i do know that my `assert` checks right now are far from good and i am looking to improve them. currently i am stuck on getting the full file paths for every file inside the zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether these files **exist** within the zip file, you can use [`Files.exist(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-).

If you want to go further and check the actual content, you can either unzip into a different temporary directory, or ask Java to [read directly from the zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file).

Comment: if you can give me a way through which i can get every file path inside the zip (file should actually exist too), i will accept your answer

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - You could use a [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) (happy to add this to my answer :), but I'm not sure why that would be helpful - you already know what files should be there, so you could check for their existence directly.

Comment: I already thought about walking the filetree, but i can't pack all the `asserts` inside 1 method which is called multiple times (some will always fail then). my "best" shot right now is to somehow get the path of my `FileSystem`  (just to be sure i access the same files), but at the moment i can't find any way to do so (except using the parameter i used to create the `FileSystem` in the first place)