# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, java-io, filenotfoundexception

Im trying to read a file in Java Eclipse. The system cant seem to find the file.

> Here is my code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.*;
  public class whyDo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("c:\\Users\\Vanessa\\Downloads\\CompLet\\CompLet\\sales\\austin.txt"));

    System.out.println(input);


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

> When I run this code I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Users\Vanessa\Downloads\CompLet\CompLet\sales\austin.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Please help. Thanks to everybody in advance.

Comment: Where is your file on your system? Did you typed 'CompLet' twice by mistake?

Comment: Its one zip folder called compLet, and then its a regular folder called CompLet, thats the reason why it's two CompLets, I even put the file in the source folder of the project, eclipse lets me drag it over. The system cant find it

Comment: your local disk C is lower case. doubt it has lower case name

Answer (score 0):

As backslashes are used, it is safe to assume that the operation system is some version of Windows, so case does not matter. I suggest using forward slashes (for readability), Java can handle them. To read a zip file, see [Read Content from Files which are inside Zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file).