# Reading list of xml files under a folder, within a jar

Tags: java, java-7

I have recently converted an existing *Java-application* into a **Maven-application** which is generating a **MyJar.jar** file. Also I've included the application's **resource xml files** inside a folder named **"MyXml"** and packaged it in that jar.

Now I need to read that list of xml files within that folder inside the jar and iterate over the files. I am using *linux environment*, and my java code is getting `Null pointer` exception while trying to access that folder inside the jar.

The folder path in the Jar is :

```
String folderPath = "app/tools/Tool1/MyJar.jar/MyXml/";
```

The java code which is throwing exception is:

```
final File folder = new File(folderPath);
for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (fileEntry.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml")) {
        System.out.println("Xml File name : "+fileEntry.getName());
    }
}
```

In the for-loop , **"folder"** object is getting null and throwing exception. Can't we mention a file-path inside a "jar" using java?

I saw some examples from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar), but there it's reading only particular file from jar, not the list of files. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: The path you are using is not a valid path, this is a valid path `app/tools/Tool1/MyJar.jar` but the bit on the end is not. You will need to use a library that can open the contents of an archive/jar file, or you will need to extract the contents from the jar file before you attempt to read the xml files `app/tools/Tool1/extractedFiles/MyXml/`

Comment: You can make use of the NIO API `FileSystem` like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413531/1270000

Comment: Okay, so without extracting the jar, I cannot read the internal resource files anyhow. Let me try to extract the file using **linux shell script** then. Hopefully it will be extracted in the same folder location that of the jar. I will reply, if it works. Thanks.

Comment: You can read the contents of a jar/archive without extracting it, you just need to use the correct library/API. But a more simple approach is to extract it first, then you can use regular file paths.

Comment: Yes, I extracted first using shell-script and access like regular files. Thanks for your suggestion. Initially I thought without extracting I can use the internal folders and files. Anyway thanks.