# Put zip files from local directory into a list in java springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, zip

Is there a way to put a directory full of zip files inside a list in a java springboot application? Say for example in my local:

`/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent`

There is a bunch of zip files and trg files, and I want to load these into eclipse java and look at the contents inside of each one (this is where the list comes in from I assume), how would I do that?

I tried doing

```
String folder1path = "/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent";

List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(new File(folder1path).listFiles());

logger.info(fileList);
```

But this results in an list that looks like:

```
[
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip1.zip
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip2.trg
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip5.zip
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip3.zip
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip4.zip
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip1.trg
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip2.zip
/Macintosh HD/Systems/Volumes/Macintosh HD/folder1/profile/sent/testZip4.trg
...
]
```

I haven't worked with this kind of stuff before but this isn't a "Zip" type file I think? It's a type File, but it has the path string in front. I don't think I can even open these zips either, so I was wondering if there was like a Zip type in java, and then I could access the contents inside the zip (it would be mostly excel spreadsheets inside, but I don't need to access the excel spreadsheets)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have so far is good?  You have all the zip file names.

If you want to access the contents of the zip files (unzipping), then there are a few options.  The JDK has java.util.zip.ZipFile OR you can try existing tools such as zip4j:

```
new ZipFile("filename.zip").extractAll("/destination_directory");
```

Possible helpful stackoverflow:

[What is a good Java library to zip/unzip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files)

========= Edited:

**Get FileAttributes, then use the lastModifiedTime method:**

```
try {

    BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(new File("C:\\some_file.zip").toPath(),BasicFileAttributes.class);
    
    System.out.println(fileAttributes.lastModifiedTime());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There are other ways of listing a directory:

**List all files end with .java**

```
try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\projects"))) {

    List<String> result = walk.map(x -> x.toString())
            .filter(f -> f.endsWith(".java")).collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.forEach(System.out::println);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-list-all-files-in-a-directory/

Comment: i found it weird that i was using the "File" type though, because does a .zip count as a File type in java? It has that path attached to the front, but I was thinking it would directly just have the zip file name. Like instead of specifying an existing zip file name in "new ZipFile(...)", is there a way for java to already know that its a ZipFile type?

Comment: a ZipFile is a File.  When you list a directory, it returns the all the (Files), with their extensions.  It is up to you how to handle them? .  If a file ends with .jpg (It is still a file), but you would need a program to view it as an Image.   Same with a .zip (It is a file), you just need a way to unzip it.  Java provides that option if needed, plus other libs.    It doesnt load up a list of [ZipFile,ZipFile,ZipFile] by default.  You can do that yourself i you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file

Comment: is there a way to grab the date modified of the ZIP file itself, and not the actual files inside the zip file?

Comment: @stackerstack Yes I updated the answer to show you how to get the lastModifiedTime of the zipfile (NOT its contents)