# How do I get multiple InputStreams for each entry of a ZipInputStream, to read from those InputStreams later?

Tags: java, zip, java-io

When we create a `ZipInputStream` `z`, we call `getNextEntry` on it and then read from `z`, in order to get the contents of the next file. I, however, need to get `ZipInputStream`s for those files to read from them later. How do I do that? Just create `n` `ZipInputStreams`, and call `getNextEntry` on the first one 1 time, on the second one 2 times, ..., on the nth one n times? Is there a more elegant way to do that than this?

I can't just read each entry into an array of bytes, because that will consume too much RAM, when the files are large and the max size of such a file can only be 2 gigs (we can't create `byte[]` arrays larger than that in Java), but I have larger files.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It shouldn't take long to test your guess.

Comment: I literally wrote the only option I came up with in the first paragraph. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Does that option work? Does it work on windows where file locking rules are different?

Comment: You may straight-up not be able to do this.  You'll have to figure out an alternate approach.

Comment: @LouisWasserman found an answer. Thanks.

Comment: You don't. It is a serial medium. You can't do this, unless you're prepared to load the whole thing into memory, which is hardly the point of ZIP.

Comment: @user207421 yes you can, i just showed it

Comment: I suspect the best approach would be to pass in a callable object to the method which traverses the ZipInputStream, and have that method invoke the callable for each zip entry.  That callable object could be a java.util.concurrent.Callable, or it could be an implementation of a custom functional interface with a method like `void processZipEntry(InputStream entryStream) throws IOException;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote this (it's in scala though, because I use scala, not Java.

```
import java.io.{FileInputStream, InputStream}
import java.util.Scanner
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipFile, ZipInputStream}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object ZipTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val zipFile = new ZipFile("/path/to/file")
    val entries = zipFile.entries()
    val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[InputStream]
    while (entries.hasMoreElements) {
      val entry = entries.nextElement()
      if(!entry.isDirectory) {
        val stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry)
        listBuffer.addOne(stream)
      }
    }
    // small usage example
    var scanner = new Scanner(listBuffer(2))
    while(scanner.hasNextLine){
      println(scanner.nextLine())
    }

    scanner = new Scanner(listBuffer(0))
    while(scanner.hasNextLine){
      println(scanner.nextLine())
    }
  }
}
```

I actually found this approach in the top answer from here: [Read Content from Files which are inside Zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file)