# Parsing xml against xsd from a zip in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I have a .zip file that contains .xml and .xsd file.

I'm reading it with a code similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473256/reading-text-files-in-a-zip-archive). Now, when I try to parse the .xml I get an error that schema is not found. How do I load the .xsd beforehand and then parse the .xml using that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the ZipInputStream from the ZipFile - [Reading text files in a zip archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473256/reading-text-files-in-a-zip-archive)
2. Use javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html

   SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
   Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdZipInputStream));
   Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
   validator.validate(xml);

Comment: One thing to watch out for when using a StreamSource with an InputStream is that unless you call setSystemId(), the base URI will be unknown, which means references to external entities will fail to resolve. Setting the base URI to a resource in a ZIP file requires use of the non-standard zip file URI format, which not all software supports.