# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 449 but got 455 bytes)

Tags: java, file, zip, unzip

Copy files from one zipfile subfolder to other zipfile subfolder. `version` and `folder` are subfolders name getting from frontend.

```
public String restore(String jobId, String version, String folder) {
    String fileName = String.valueOf(jobId) + ".zip";
    String versions[] = version.replaceAll("'", "")
        .replace("[", "")
        .replace("]", "")
        .split(",");
    String folders[] = folder.replaceAll("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
    ArrayList<String> listofVersion, listofFolder = new ArrayList<>();

    File destinationFile = new File(env.getProperty("file.path") + fileName);
    File sourceFile = new File(env.getProperty("file.arcivePath") + fileName);

    FileInputStream in;
    FileOutputStream out;
    ZipInputStream zin;
    ZipOutputStream zipout;
    int BUFFER = (int) sourceFile.length();

    if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
            zipout = new ZipOutputStream(out); //I get the "out" object from the servlet which tells the content type and and final zip file location.
            ZipEntry zEntry, ze;
            in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            zin = new ZipInputStream(in);
            while ((zEntry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println(zEntry);
                String entry = zEntry.getName();
                String entryList[] = entry.split("/");
                if (zEntry.isDirectory() && (entryList.length <= 1)) {
                    zipout.putNextEntry(zEntry);
                } else {
                    if (entryList.length >= 2) {
                        listofVersion = listVersionRestore(fileName);
                        for (int j = 0; j < versions.length; j++) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < listofVersion.size(); i++) {
                                if (listofVersion.get(i).equals(versions[j])) {
                                    if ((entryList.length == 2) && entryList[1].equals(versions[j])) {
                                        zipout.putNextEntry(zEntry);
                                    }
                                    if (entryList.length >= 3) {
                                        listofFolder = listFolderRestore(fileName, versions[j]);
                                        for (int l = 0; l < folders.length; l++) {
                                            for (int k = 0; k < listofFolder.size(); k++) {
                                                if (listofFolder.get(k).equals(folders[l])) {
                                                    if ((entryList.length == 3) && entryList[1].equals(versions[j]) && entryList[2].equals(folders[l])) {
                                                        zipout.putNextEntry(zEntry);
                                                    }

                                                    if ((entryList.length == 4) && entryList[1].equals(versions[j]) && entryList[2].equals(folders[l])) {
                                                        zipout.putNextEntry(zEntry);
                                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];
                                                        int len = 0;
                                                        while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                                            zipout.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                                        }

                                                        zipout.closeEntry();
                                                        in.close();
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            zipout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error";
        }
    } else {
        return "Already Exists";
    }
    return "RestoredSuccessfully";
}
```

Getting error as follow:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 449 but got 455 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(Unknown Source)
at prj.iopo.filesystem.FileSystemHandler.restore(FileSystemHandler.java:148)
at prj.iopo.filesystem.FileSystemHandler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f51baf3f.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at prj.iopo.filesystem.FileSystemHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d76d700.restore(<generated>)
at prj.iopo.controller.JobController.restore(JobController.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)89765042/1/2l/FS-restore.txt
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm getting an error at `zipout.closeEntry();`
But I can't remove this line.

Answer (score 7):

Resolved error by using new stream with new zipentry.

```
loc_ze = new ZipEntry(zEntry.getName()); 
zipout.putNextEntry(loc_ze); 
zipfile = new ZipFile(sourceFile); 
InputStream stream = zipfile.getInputStream(zEntry); 
while ((len = stream.read(b)) != -1) { 
    zipout.write(b, 0, len); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a new `ZEntry` object to put in the ZIP output stream. You can't reuse one from a ZIP input stream: it contains stuff that the ZIP output stream wants to determine for itself. Use the appropriate constructor to copy what is really needed from the source `ZIPEntry`.

Comment: Can you give any sample code.    I modified my code as like below but I am getting same error.   zEntry = zin.getNextEntry();  ze = new ZipEntry(zEntry);   zipout.putNextEntry(ze);

Comment: Don't construct a new ZipEntry using the ZipEntry from the zip you're reading from. Construct it like: new ZipEntry(zEntry.getName()). This was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest solution is **TrueZip** (https://truezip.java.net/), see this thread [Appending files to a zip file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java)

EJP is correct. For copying files inside the same archive you need two ZipEntry objects because every `ZipEntry` object represents one file or directory in the zip archive

See this thread [Reading text files in a zip archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473256/reading-text-files-in-a-zip-archive) and this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm

You need a `ZipFile` object to which you pass the location path of your zip file

`ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("/<path>/yourZip.zip");`

Then you create an enumeration of all elements of the ZipFile object

`Enumeration entries = zf.entries();`

As you want to copy the files in the archive you can skip this.
**[** To read the content of the entries use an InputStream (binary to ASCII)  wrapped into a  BufferedReader (reads a textfile, with format characters like EOL or EOF)`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));` **]**

An alternative method is `ZipInputStream` / `ZipOutputStream`

The following code reads the content of a zip archive (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class ReadZip {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("ReadZip.zip");
      Enumeration entries = zf.entries();

      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          System.in));
      while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Read " + ze.getName() + "?");
        String inputLine = input.readLine();
        if (inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
          long size = ze.getSize();
          if (size > 0) {
            System.out.println("Length is " + size);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(zf.getInputStream(ze)));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static copyZip() throws IOException {
    try (final ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(...);
         final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(...)
    ) {
        copyZipContent(zis, zos);
    }
}

static void copyZipContent(final ZipInputStream zis, final ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry zisEntry;
    while ((zisEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        ZipEntry zosEntry = new ZipEntry(zisEntry.getName());
        zosEntry.setComment(zisEntry.getComment());
        zosEntry.setExtra(zisEntry.getExtra());
        zos.putNextEntry(zosEntry);
        IOUtils.copy(zis, zos);
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
    zos.finish();
}
```